# Magento model listing/get function

Tags: magento, model, magento-1.4

I'm trying to learn how to use Magento models, but I'm getting very impatient and keep getting interrupted by client phone calls....Can someone just tell me how to achieve the following:

```
SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE emaillike '%gmail%' and taxnumber = 300
//Then print the results in php
```

I'm looking for code that might look something like

```
$model = new UserTable();
$results = $model->getWhere(array('email'=>'%gmail%', tax=>300));
print_r($results);
```

or something to that effect;

Comment: try switching your phone off...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$collection = $customer->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('taxvat', 300)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('email', array('like'=>'%gmail%'))
            ->load();
print_r($collection->toArray());
```

<sub>**P.S.** When you have time [the knowledge base](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-7-advanced-orm-entity-attribute-value) makes a good primer.</sub>

Comment: thanks, but I get zero results back, even though i know the database has a user with the email test@test.com.  Here's my code: `$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('email','test@test.com')->toArray();`   any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I've added a `load()` call, usually it isn't needed but I think I recall `toArray()` behaving differently.

Comment: great, it worked.  I also tried remove the ->load() call and put the collection through a foreach loop to grab the first item, and that worked too.